# Material UI component (Autocomplete) not stretching within Grid even with fullWidth={true}

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, grid, material-ui

Here is my Sandbox for this project: https://codesandbox.io/s/gridnotworkingchildnotstretching-vk6ld

In Home.jsx, I have a row `Grid` with a height of `100vh` to center everything horizontally. In it, I have a column `Grid` with `alignItems="stretch"` to actually put my content in a column, which includes a `Typography`, then a `SearchBar` that is actually an `Autocomplete` component, and a `Button`. Since I plan on using the `SearchBar` elsewhere, I pass a `home` prop to it that is set to true if we're at the homepage, which we are. I want the `Typography` and `Button` to be centered, while the `SearchBar` stretched to the full width of its parent, which is `xs={10} sm={4}`.

The `Typography` and the `Button` are looking like how I want them to, but for some reason the `SearchBar` isn't stretching to the width of the Grid. I even set `fullWidth={home}` with the `Autocomplete` component but it's still not stretching. Could you please tell me what went wrong in my code, or if it is possible to do what I want to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the style prop you're passing to your Autocomplete component in `searchBar.jsx` line 37. Try Removing `style={{ width: 300 }}`.

Comment: omg I didn't even notice that. I was trying things out and I guess I forgot about it. it's working now. thank you!